# Iterating though a 3D JSON array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a script that iterate through a JSON array that comes back from an AJAX request. I want it to iterate through each key (string) and value (boolean), and add a CSS class to an object where the ID matches the name of the key.

An additional complexity arises because the array is 3D, the actual values fall under the 'boxes' sub-array.

I sucessfully get the JSON back from the server, the problem arises when I try and iterate though it; I can get the value of the 'expired' variable, but not anything else.

JSON from the server:

```
{
    "expired": false,
    "boxes": {
        "read_curriculum__c": false,
        "update_salesforce__c": false,
        "slack_add__c": true,
        "orientation__c": false,
        "survey__c": true
    }
}
```

On the page:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {  
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
      var responseObj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
      if(responseObj.expired == false)
      {
        for(var i = 0; i < responseObj.boxes.length; i++) // Take however many items are in the boxes array.
        {
          if(responseObj.boxes[i] == true) //Go through each one and check if it's true
          {
            var element = getElementById(responseObj.boxes[i]); //Select the element on the page with the same ID
            element.classList.add("true"); //Add the class 'true'
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/onboard/onboard.php?function=fetch", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

All the variations I have tried give me either 'undefined' or 'Object' as a result. I'm also struggling to work out how to separate the key from the value. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no array there. Is that the whole JSON or just a part of it?

Comment: It's not in `array` form. If you want key names then you can use `Object.keys(objectName)`

Answer (score 1):

It's not an array, it's just a single object with another object nested within it. You can iterate over the keys of the object with `for (var i in object)`.

```
  if(!responseObj.expired)
  {
    for(var i in responseObj.boxes)
    {
      if(responseObj.boxes[i]) //Go through each one and check if it's true
      {
        var element = getElementById(i); //Select the element on the page with the same ID
        element.classList.add("true"); //Add the class 'true'
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it still doesn't seem to work. I've confirmed that `responseObj.expired` gives a result, but when I include the for loop I get the error "responseObj is not defined". Which is odd because it clearly is.

Comment: Either you have a typo, or that's not really the error you're getting.

Comment: I had a typo `reponseObj` (missing the first "s"), I just fixed it.

Comment: Yes that typo was it - I hadn't looked closely enough. Thank you!

Comment: That's why it's best to copy and paste error messages, instead of retyping.